# Casio Calculator How to find tan2x,sin2x,cos2x?

Tags: calculator, trigonometry

Is there any way I can use my casio calculator(fx-991es) to do some trigonometric functions like finding tan2x. By tan2x I did not meant tan^2x. But something like tan2x= 2tanx/1-tan^2x. Is there any direct way to do that in calculator

I want to do similar thing for sin2x. which stands for 2.sinx.cosx. I know that I can manually do that but it takes time. So if there is some way please help me

Comment: Enter *x*, press __X__, __2__, __=__, __sin__?

Comment: @jasonharper dont joke please

Comment: Your description of what you wamt to calculate is not clear. Either find a better way to phrase it, e.g. by using the syntax of a widely used programming language (in this community probably the best way) or use pictures of correct math formulas (keep the best text representation you can come up with however) or provide some explanatory examples of input values and expected output, that would at least facility guessing what you mean.

Comment: Is what you want to calculate `tan(2*x)`, `tan(x*x)`, `2*tan(x)/(1-tan(x)*tan(x))`, `sin(2*x)`? Those are my guess, but as you see I am unsuere what you mean and might not even have included what you mean in my guesses.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply type `sin(2*x)`. It will do the work. Thank you